# un evento onclick javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo un boton con un evento JS por ejempo  donde num es el valor de un input en el mismo formulario, la pregunta es: se puede hacer eso de enviar como parametro un valor de input a travez de una funcion en un boton?

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow @JP2020 te invito a que te des un paseo por el [tour] para poder generar buenas preguntas en el sitio y evitar que estas sean cerradas por superiores. tambien te invito a leer este articulo [ask], por esta misma razón, de lo contrarió la pregunta puede terminar cerrada o puntuada negativamente.

Comment: Algo que si podemos hacer es recomendarte fuentes de información, ya sea para que tu mismo resuelvas tu duda y respondas a tu pregunta (se puede hacer), o para que te des una idea de mas o menos como hacer aquello que requieres, y así poder editar la pregunta y poner aquello que haz intentado para poder nosotros ayudarte, checa por ejemplo esto de aquí, seguro te será de ayuda: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: Te recomiendo mucho las paginas w3school y developer.mozilla estas dan una gran cantidad de información concisa correcta e importante a los programadores sobre diferentes temas, sobre todo para javascript, ademas estas dos paginas se consideran practicamente las mas usadas para conseguir información de este tipo en la red y encima se consideran fuentes oficiales.

Comment: De acuerdo contigo en las recomendaciones @Riven menos en w3schools, navega un poco en la red y verás que esa no es una fuente considerada de calidad, además que no es oficial pues es un proyecto privado y no esta asociada con ninguna entidad relevante

Answer (score 0):

¿Te refieres a algo como esto?

```js
function hazAlgo(num){
  alert(num);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num" value="45"/>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Presiona" onclick="hazAlgo(document.getElementById('num').value)"/>
```

La verdad es algo muy simple, te recomiendo este sitio: [freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/) donde puedes aprender varios temas entre ellos desarrollo web, javascript, algoritmos.

Tambien puedes checar documentacion en [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).

Comment: Me tente a responder también pero la idea era que él o ella misma investigara carnala, antes de nosotros darle una respuesta :c.

Comment: Entiendo... U_U